# How to overlay Historic map onto Google Earth using QGIS?

Tags: cartography, georeferencing

I am very new to QGIS. I have a Plat Map of my home town from the early 1900's that I would like to overlay on Google Earth.

The problem I'm having is the map will not line up. I can get roads to line up in one section but not the whole map. I believe this is due to to a poor scan that is not flat in all areas (not sure).

Is there a way to manipulate the map by referencing multiple areas on both maps? I've read some tutorials on georeferencing, but I'm not really sure if this is the right direction or how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a default plugin for qgis called georeferencer. That would do exactly what you need. It has a nice [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html).

Answer (score 3):

Georeferencing in QGIS is done via the ‘Georeferencer GDAL’ plugin. This is a core plugin - meaning it is already part of your QGIS installation. You just need to enable it. Go to Plugins ‣ Manage and Install Plugins and enable the Georeferencer GDAL plugin in the Installed tab.

You will select your overlay image, your CRS, and then manually select your reference points (points that are shared on both maps)  and then run the tool and your image will now be georeferenced.

see:

http://courses.umass.edu/nrc297s/PDFs/Lab_Georeferencing_with_QGIS.pdf

https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/how-to-georeference-a-map-in-qgis/

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html

http://www.digital-geography.com/qgis-tutorial-i-how-to-georeference-a-map/#.VsHbdGHXKUk

http://glaikit.org/2011/03/27/image-georeferencing-with-qgis/